# How to create alerts through bicep for KQL commands

Tags: kql, azure-cloud-services, azure-monitoring, azure-bicep, azure-alerts

We are trying to create Azure alerts through bicep and KQL queries and using for loop to create multiple alerts. Unfortunately we are getting the errors while executing the code

alerts.bicep

```
   // Parameters
   @description('Log alerts parameter from j son')
   param logAlertParam object

   @description('Location of Resource group ')
   param location string

   @description('Id of the action group')
   param actiongroups_rcp_externalid string

   @description('Id of the log analtyics workspace')
   param workspaceResourceId string



  resource logAlertQuerySymbolicname 'Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules@2022-06-15' 
  = [ for component in logAlertParam.infraComponents: {
      name: component.alertRuleName
      location: location
      kind: 'LogAlert'
      properties: {
         actions: {
           actionGroups: [
          actiongroups_rcp_externalid
          ]
           customProperties: {}
           }
        autoMitigate: false
        checkWorkspaceAlertsStorageConfigured: false
           criteria: {
             allOf: [
             {
                query: component.queryParam
                timeAggregation: component.timeaggregation
                dimensions: []
                operator: component.operator
                threshold: 1
                failingPeriods: {
                numberOfEvaluationPeriods: 1
                minFailingPeriodsToAlert: 1
                    }
                  }
                 ]
                }
             displayName: component.alertRuleName
             enabled: true
             evaluationFrequency: component.evaluationFrequency
             scopes: [
              workspaceResourceId
              ]
            severity: component.severity
            skipQueryValidation: false
           targetResourceTypes: component.targetResourceType
           windowSize: component.windowsize
            }
          }]
```

parameters.json

```
          {
             "logAlertParam": {
                 "infraComponents": [
                     {   
                       "alertRuleName": "AKS-Cluster-Deletion",
                       "queryParam": "AzureActivity\n| where ResourceProviderValue 
                            contains \"MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE\" and 
                            OperationNameValue contains 
                            \"MICROSOFT.CONTAINERSERVICE/MANAGEDCLUSTERS/DELETE\"\n| 
                            where ActivityStatusValue contains \"Success\"\n| project 
                            TimeGenerated, _ResourceId, Caller, ActivityStatusValue, 
                            CallerIpAddress\n",
                      "timeaggregation": "Count",
                      "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
                      "evaluationFrequency": "P1D",                
                      "severity": 0,
                      "ResourceType": 
                     "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",      
                      "windowSize": "P1D",
                      "threshold": 1
                           }            
                          ]
                        }
                      }
```

While running with this configuration we are getting following error.

```
         2023-02-20T14:59:20.6470013Z ERROR: {"status":"Failed","error": 
         {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment 
         operation  failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see 
         https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details": 
          [{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": 
         {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The 
        'AzureAsyncOperationWaiting' resource operation completed with terminal 
        provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        
        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource 
        deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. 
        Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.\",\r\n        
        \"details\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n            
       \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": 
        \\\"BadRequest\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"{\\\\r\\\\n  
        \\\\\\\"error\\\\\\\": {\\\\r\\\\n    \\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\": 
       \\\\\\\"InvalidRequestContent\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\\n    \\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\": 
        \\\\\\\"The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error 
       converting value 
       **\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" to 
       type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path 
      'properties.targetResourceTypes', line 1, position 1185.'**\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\\n  
      }\\\\r\\\\n}\\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    
     ]\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

Query is providing the output as expected on log analytics workspace, however when we passing the same query to bicep file its giving the above error. What is going wrong the the config?

Comment: If you are posting from a mobile phone, and cannot produce upper-case letters easily, please wait until you can access a desktop machine. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom or discussion forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting targetResourceTypes as below resolved the issue:

```
    targetResourceTypes: [
        component.targetResourceType
    ]
```